# Express: fetch unable to set cookie

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, cookies

I use the below to set a cookie using express.

```
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.get('/a', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    res.cookie('aaa', 'bbb');
    res.send('something');
});

app.post('/b', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    res.cookie('ccc', 'ddd');
    res.send('something');
})
```

If visit directly a, can set cookie.

```
<form method="POST" action="/bb">
    <label>name</label>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
<div id='test'>fetch</div>
<script>
    var test = document.getElementById('test');
    test.onclick = function () {
        fetch('/b', {
            method: 'POST'
        }).then( (data) => {
            data.text().then(function(data) {console.log(data)});
        })
    }
</script>
```

If click submit, can set cookie,
But if click test, can not set cookie.

Why?

Comment: What is `fetch('/b', {method: 'POST'})`?

Comment: How are you checking that the cookie isn't being set?

Comment: I edit the problem @hjpotter92

Comment: visit a, console it @robertklep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `fetch()`, you need to explicitly tell it that cookies should be sent with a request:

```
fetch('/b', { method : 'post', credentials : 'include' })
```

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included)